# Pandas To_Excel parsing problem - outputting only 1 file

Tags: python, json, pandas, export-to-excel

Hello I have working code like this:

```
import pandas as pdfrom pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import json
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

with open('yieldfull.json') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

df_json = json_normalize(data)
df_json_stripped = data[0]
platform_dict = df_json_stripped['result']
platform_names = []

for key in platform_dict:
    platform_names.append(key)

for name in platform_names:
    if name == 'Autofarm':
        vault_name_df = json_normalize(pd.DataFrame(dict([(k , pd.Series(v)) for k,v in df_json['result.'+name+'.LPVaults.vaults'].items()]))[0])['name']
        current_token_0 = json_normalize(pd.DataFrame(dict([(k , pd.Series(v)) for k,v in df_json['result.'+name+'.LPVaults.vaults'].items()]))[0])['LPInfo.currentToken0']
        current_token_1 = json_normalize(pd.DataFrame(dict([(k , pd.Series(v)) for k,v in df_json['result.'+name+'.LPVaults.vaults'].items()]))[0])['LPInfo.currentToken1']
        df_json = pd.DataFrame({'Vault_Name':vault_name_df, 'Current_Token_0':current_token_0 , 'Current_Token_1':current_token_1})
        df_json.to_excel('Output_'+name+'.xlsx', index = False)
        platform_names.remove(name)
    elif name == 'Acryptos':
        vault_name_df = json_normalize(pd.DataFrame(dict([(k , pd.Series(v)) for k,v in df_json['result.'+name+'.vaults.vaults'].items()]))[0])['name']
        price_USD = json_normalize(pd.DataFrame(dict([(k , pd.Series(v)) for k,v in df_json['result.'+name+'.vaults.vaults'].items()]))[0])['priceInUSDDepositToken']
        current_token_0 = json_normalize(pd.DataFrame(dict([(k , pd.Series(v)) for k,v in df_json['result.'+name+'.vaults.vaults'].items()]))[0])['currentTokens']
        deposited_token = json_normalize(pd.DataFrame(dict([(k, pd.Series(v)) for k,v in df_json['result.'+name+'.vaults.vaults'].items()]))[0])['depositedTokens']
        df_json = pd.DataFrame({'Vault_Name':vault_name_df, 'Price_USD':price_USD, 'Current_Token_0':current_token_0, 'Deposited_Token':deposited_token})
        df_json.to_excel('Output_'+name+'.xlsx', index = False)
    else:
        pass
```

Problem is: If I leave it like this it only outputs for first `if`. When I comment out that `if` section it will successfully output `elif`, but I can't get it to output 2 files whatever I do. Any ideas?

Error I'm getting for Acryptos:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Adam\PycharmProjects\Scrapy_Things\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3080, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 101, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 4554, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 4562, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'result.Acryptos.vaults.vaults'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Adam/PycharmProjects/Scrapy_Things/yieldwatch/yieldwatch/spiders/JsonExcel.py", line 27, in <module>
    vault_name_df = json_normalize(pd.DataFrame(dict([(k , pd.Series(v)) for k,v in df_json['result.'+name+'.vaults.vaults'].items()]))[0])['name']
  File "C:\Users\Adam\PycharmProjects\Scrapy_Things\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3024, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\Adam\PycharmProjects\Scrapy_Things\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3082, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'result.Acryptos.vaults.vaults'
```

But if I comment out Autofarm and just process if for Acryptos is outputs excel just fine.

Comment: Please include any relevant information [as text directly into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), do not link or embed external images of source code or data. Images make it difficult to efficiently assist you as they cannot be searched or copied and offer poor usability. See: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/15497888)

Comment: Done :) thanks for advice.

Comment: pls note, `elif` will only run if your `if` is False. may I know what is the data in `platform_names`?

Comment: Platform names is a list consisting only names for purposes of building a valid dataframe. Its weird tho because if I put Acryptos from elif as first "If" - basicly switch it around. It will also get Autofarm output but skip Acryptos. I can get acryptos only if I comment out Autofarm. I get Autofarm everytime tho - no matter where it is in a loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please remove the below line from your code

```
platform_names.remove(name)
```

debug code:

```
platform_names=['Autofarm','Acryptos']
for name in platform_names:
    if name == 'Autofarm':
        print("Autofarm")
        #platform_names.remove(name) # remove this line
    elif name == "Acryptos":
        print("Acryptos")
```

you have initially created

`df_json = json_normalize(data)`

and also in loop, you are overwriting it -->

```
df_json = pd.DataFrame({'Vault_Name':vault_name_df, 'Current_Token_0':current_token_0 , 'Current_Token_1':current_token_1}) 
df_json.to_excel('Output_'+name+'.xlsx', index = False)
```

so change the name in loop and it will be okay.

Comment: Yeah sorry this line was useless, forgot to remove it before posting a question - it doesn't affect the results tho.

Comment: no worries, can i get your `platform_names` list, to run both files it should have these two entries `['Autofarm','Acryptos']`

Comment: Yea it does have them. I can't really paste error that im getting here because its too long but basicly - if I have acryptos along with autofarm in a loop I get KeyError. If i comment out Autofarm and leave Acryptos only it succesfully outputs excel file for it. I'm really puzzled here. That being said my platform_names is:['watchBalance', 'currencies', 'Alpha', 'HyperJump', 'BeefyFinance', 'Blizzard', 'MDex', 'PancakeSwap', 'Jetfuel', 'bDollar', 'Autofarm', 'Acryptos', 'bunny', 'CreamFinance', 'Venus', 'walletBalance']

Comment: The next step is, pls paste the key error in your question section.

Comment: Done - I pasted it all from. Weirdest thing is - if I just process that if then it goes just fine. It seems its some pandas thing

Comment: when you are processing `'Acryptos'` then there something incorrect on df_json dataframe which is throwing key error.  df_json['result.Acryptos.vaults.vaults']. are you all set? if not then not sure if you can share file `yieldfull.json`

Comment: But when I just process 'Acryptos' it outputs excel just fine. Yieldfull.json is quite a nested mess but its not a problem of structure as I can process this path just fine if its not a loop. Its a looping problem

Comment: you have initially created `df_json = json_normalize(data)` and also in loop you are overwritting it --> `df_json = pd.DataFrame({'Vault_Name':vault_name_df, 'Current_Token_0':current_token_0 , 'Current_Token_1':current_token_1})
        df_json.to_excel('Output_'+name+'.xlsx', index = False)` so change the name in loop  and it will be okay.

Comment: Omg you're the boss! So simple haha